# How to change a property of a UserControl's child element on a IsMouseOver trigger?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a custom usercontrol which has an outline border which i want to highlight somehow while the mouse is over the control. 
I tried to add a style with mouse over trigger to the usercontrol but there didn't find out how to target the child border (style targetname seems not to find "OuterBorder").

Adding the trigger to the border itself seems to not work at all.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CCC.Controls.Test"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CCC.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="240" d:DesignWidth="182" Height="240" Width="182" Margin="2" >
    <!-- tried to add trigger here too as UserControl.Style -->
    <Grid>
        ... <!-- other controls inside here -->
        <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" Width="182" CornerRadius="3"  BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#acacac" Margin="0,00,0,0" Height="240" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!-- doesnt work -->
            <Border.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's not possible offer specific advice. There's nothing in your code example that uses a "target" for a style (whatever you meant by that...`Style` only has `TargetType`, not "targetname"), so there's no way to know what you tried. Maybe you want to use a `DataTrigger` instead of `Trigger`, which would allow the `Border`'s style to monitor the `UserControl.IsMouseOver` state? Unfortunately, it's just not clear what you're asking here, and without a good code example it's not possible to make a good guess.

Comment: There is nothing that uses the TargetType because it didn't work out at all. So i left out these parts of the code. what is left is pretty complete tho: the "..." part can just be left out as it doesnt matter which/how many controls will be in there later.

A Datatrigger on the UserControl was something i tried to make work but I didn't get the Border to react. Maybe because of the reason given by AnjumSKhan below, I will try it again now with his hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set a `Local Value` of `BorderBrush` property to `acacac`. This local value will take precedence. See [Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx).

1. Set `Background=Transparent` for the `Border`.
2. Remove `BorderBrush` from `Border` tag and make following changes :

   ```
   <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#acacac"/>
    </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
   ```

Comment: thanks for the hint! 
This helped already somehow but the Border now really only changes while the mouse is over the 3px of the border around the control.

As soon as the mouse is inside the Control completely the Border is switching back to grey. Maybe the Trigger really must come from the UserControl parent and not from the border itself?

Comment: what is your requirement exactly ?

Comment: I wanted that the border to be in red while the mouse is over the whole control. I already found out now with your help: I still had to add `Background="Transparent" ` to the border, now everthing works as wanted. 

Thanks again!